# Laravel 419 expired after click login

Tags: php, laravel

Before I had login was working totally fine.

After artisan make:auth existing register and login page when you clicking showing 419 expired tried to find any ways and  no luck. there is all exists meant @csrf token. I've tried to clear cache and regenerate key and, {{ csrf_token() }}. Laravel deafult auth that's I'm sure haven't deleted anything.
Clear cache : php artisan cache:clear Generate new app key : php artisan key:generate.
Any thoughts ?

Comment: when you click login open developer tools and go to network. check the request that was just sent and if it has the `X-CSRF-TOKEN` token in request headers.

Comment: nope, doesn't show X-CSRF-TOKEN

Comment: Documentlogin 419 document Other 2.3 kB 75 ms Stylesheetcss?family=Nunito 200 stylesheet login (disk cache) 1 ms FontXRXV3I6Li01BKofINeaBTMnFcQ.woff2  Otherfavicon.ico

Comment: check your session.php

Comment: thanks, but what do I need to check on session.php?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a solution. After removing URL from SESSION_DOMAIN on .env problem solved. Thanks all worked hard for me.